# Drawer navigation not displaying in react-navigation

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I am using react-navigation 3 versions with react native 0.59 version.
I am using switch navigation for the login code. Once I got login it's redirecting to the home screen and other navigation from home screen working fine but drawer icon not displaying.

My navigator.js

```
export const AppStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
        headerRight:soundicon()
    }
  }, 
  withdraw: {
    screen: WithdrawScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
        headerRight:soundicon()
    }
  }, 
  deposite: {
    screen: DepositScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
        headerRight:soundicon()
    }
  }, 

  money: {
    screen: MoneyScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
        headerRight:soundicon()
    }
  }
});

export const drawermenu  = createDrawerNavigator({
        Home: AppStack,
})

export const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({
    SignIn: {
        screen: SignInScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
        header: null,
        }
    },
    Signup:  {
        screen: SignupScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
        }
    },
    ForgotPassword:  {
        screen: ForgotPasswordScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
        }
    }

});

export const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
{
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    App: drawermenu,
    Auth: AuthStack,
},
{
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
});

export const AppNavigatorObj = createAppContainer(AppNavigator)
```

Comment: To display drawer icon you have to put touchableopacity in header and set some actions on it.Drawer icon is not default here.Try that. May be that will solve your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is you can open the drawer by sliding right,if you want to open it with a icon you have to make a header component and use it on screens you want. Heres a nice example of headers: https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/header.html